# Android x86 disable USB device or driver or choose bluetooth device?

Tags: android-bluetooth, android-x86, android-usb

I'm running Android x86 on Parallels Desktop and their virtual bluetooth device simply doesn't work. I would like to use my Android-compatible USB dongle (CSR8510). I can do this with Windows 10 by disabling the virtual device in the Device Manager, but I fail to see an equivalent setting in Android.

I know the USB dongle is attached to Android x86 by running the USB Host Controller app. It shows up as 0001:0a12 CSR8510 A10

Any suggestions?